# Kendo UI: remote DataSource with local operations

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm stuck trying to improve the performance of a KendoUI-grid-based report.

It's supposed to get data from a remote data source, but perform the sorting and grouping locally.

I've explicitly disabled the 'server' options, as follows:

```
var dSource = kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            // Configure my ajax call and send the filter values
        }
    },
    serverPaging: false,
    serverGrouping: false,
    serverSorting: false
});
```

This datasource is consumed by a kendo-ui grid, with sorting enabled.

However, when I click a column and I sort it, a new ajax call is made, which is just waste of bandwidth and server resources.

I asked a wise man called "Google", but every data source example that I get is either fully local or fully remote, nothing mixed.

How can I achieve remote filtering and local sorting / grouping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration looks correct. This is the suggested way to enable local paging and sorting. I created a live demo showing a working configuration: http://jsbin.com/itaqut/1/edit

Comment: OK I've tried your demo and works, guess there's something extra in my config that needs to be checked. Thanks